# SDLC approach for small size projects

Tags: agile, scrum, sdlc

For small size projects, is it worth following the SDLC? is SCRUM/agile development a better approach?

**Edit**: The project I have in mind is a small change but it will affect multiple layers/parts of the application, so there will be 2 or 3 developers involved each from a different team, then the code will be integrated at a later step.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a small project? Are you working alone, or with a small team, or with a large team for a short time?

Comment: Also you seem to imply that Agile is an exception to the SDLC. SDLC != waterfall model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDLC stands for "software development life cycle" or sometimes "system development life cycle," and it refers to the process that you follow for developing your product. There's no single SDLC process that everyone follows -- you're free to define your own, and to change it as the project (or your organization) grows. The point is to have a defined process, preferably one that's written down, that you follow for the work related to development and maintenance of your project. The alternative is to work by the seat of your pants, making things up as you go along.

So, if you want to use Scrum or some other "agile" methodology in your process, that's perfectly fine. Just write it into your SDLC and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Agile processes work for small projects very well. We have been doing it for last 2 years on projects which lasts between 2-4 months.

The good thing about agile development is that you don't see much difference between big and small projects as most of our concentration is on the specific "sprint"s that we are currently working on.

Do not go ahead without following any SDLC processes!! You never know when your "small" project will become "big" :) I have seen many projects which start small but does not end as "small".

One of the artcle that I read was saying agile development was first thought to be good for small projects only and then moved on to big projects.

[link](https://brightgreenprojects.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/isnt-agile-just-for-small-projects-scaling-scrum/)